# Assign element from array to each table cell

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have 25 table cells and an array that randomizes values. I want to assign each value to a cell from the table.

I think that my main issue is in the following line:

```
for (i = 0; i < tablecells.length; i++) { 
        tablecells.innerHTML = BingoSquares.pop();
    };
```

What is the mistake in the above loop? Rest of code is shown below just in case its needed.

Thank you in advance

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('loginoverlay');
var tablecells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

BingoSquares=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "1", "2", "3"];



function hideOverlay(){
    overlay.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        overlay.style.display = "none"; 
    }, 1000);
};

function newCard() {
    //shuffle array:
    BingoSquares.sort(function(){
        return Math.round(Math.random());
    });

    console.log(BingoSquares.pop());


    for (i = 0; i < tablecells.length; i++) { 
        tablecells.innerHTML = BingoSquares.pop();
    };

};

document.getElementById('newsubmit').onclick = function() {
    hideOverlay();
    newCard();
};
```

Comment: Future reference, your `console.log(BingoSquares.pop())` actually pops the array so if your array was length 25 and you do the above, you will now be at length 24 since you just popped your last element out of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the elements from the array, by using `tablecells[i]`:

```
tablecells[i].innerHTML = BingoSquares.pop();
```